# SPDY is not working with OkHttp

Tags: android, retrofit, spdy, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit 1.6.1 with OkHttp 2.0.0. So far we didn't have SPDY enabled on our server but last night we've enabled it.
http://spdycheck.org/ says that SPDY is enabled on our server but when I try making an API call the logs show that HTTP/1.1 was used:

```
D/Retrofit(29455): OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
```

Do I have to do anything to enable SPDY with OkHttp or it should be detected automatically?

This is how I'm setting things up:

```
OkHttpClient okHttp = new OkHttpClient();

okHttp.setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
okHttp.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
okHttp.setWriteTimeout(15 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

OkClient okClient = new OkClient(okHttp);

mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setClient(okClient)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(mGson))
            .setErrorHandler(errorHandler)
            .setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
```

I'm testing both on Nexus 4 running stock Android 4.4.4 and on Moto G with stock rom and Android 4.4.4

Comment: Easy question: is the base URL HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, the base URL is https

Comment: Can you share the hostname?

Comment: Yep - https://www.youlocalapp.com

Comment: @JesseWilson did you manage to take a look at it?

Comment: any solution. I am having the same problem with http2

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are using okhttp2 and android devices that is below 5.0 (That does not support SPDY), so that device never attempted to use a SPDY connection. And by default it is using http1.1.

If your device is > 5.0 okhttp automatically will choose the latest protocol either SPDY or HTTP/2. but you can not set/ force it explicitly.

**Note** - Okhttp3 does not support SPDY, so will not try to make a SPDY connection.